# AWS Configuration line in swift class causes Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I building an app that allows users to communicate with an AWS Lex chatbot, however the problem is right now is when the user taps the button to begin their conversation with the bot it crashes and gives me a **Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** error on this line:

`let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: botRegion!, credentialsProvider: AWSIdentityManager.default().credentialsProvider)`

I would really like to know what is causing it to behave like this, as Xcode does not highlight any significant parts of the code.

Below is the what my code looks like in its entirety for those interested.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Photos
import JSQMessagesViewController
import AWSLex
import AWSMobileHubHelper

let ClientSenderId = "Client"
let ServerSenderId = "Server"

class JeevesChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController, JSQMessagesComposerTextViewPasteDelegate {

// The name of the bot.
var botName: String?

// The bot region
var botRegion: AWSRegionType?

// The bot alias
var botAlias: String?

// The messages communicated between the client and the server
var messages: [JSQMessage]?

// The interaction kit client
var interactionKit: AWSLexInteractionKit?

// The session attributes
var sessionAttributes: [AnyHashable: Any]?

// Contents of outgoing image
var outgoingBubbleImageData: JSQMessagesBubbleImage?

// Contents of incoming image
var incomingBubbleImageData: JSQMessagesBubbleImage?

// Used to store task completion source of iteraction kit
var textModeSwitchingCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSString>?

// The client image
var clientImage: JSQMessagesAvatarImage?

// The bot image
var serverImage: JSQMessagesAvatarImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Make the initial setup for the bot.
    // Error occurs here - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: botRegion!, credentialsProvider: AWSIdentityManager.default().credentialsProvider)

    // Setup interaction kit configuration
    let botConfig = AWSLexInteractionKitConfig.defaultInteractionKitConfig(withBotName:botName!, botAlias: botAlias!)

    // Disable automatic voice playback
    botConfig.autoPlayback = false

    // Register the interaction kit client
    AWSLexInteractionKit.register(with: configuration!, interactionKitConfiguration: botConfig, forKey: botName!)

    // Fetch and set the interaction kit client
    self.interactionKit = AWSLexInteractionKit.init(forKey: botName!)

    // Set the interaction kit delegate
    // Remove 'as? AWSLexInteractionDelegate' statement later
    self.interactionKit?.interactionDelegate = self

    // Setup JSQMessagesViewController configuration
    self.showLoadEarlierMessagesHeader = false

    // Initialise the avatars for client and server here.


    // Setup the default keyboard type.
    self.inputToolbar.contentView?.textView?.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default

    // Initialise the messages list
    self.messages = [JSQMessage]()

    // Set the colours for messages bubbles 
    let bubbleFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    self.outgoingBubbleImageData = bubbleFactory?.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreen())
    self.incomingBubbleImageData = bubbleFactory?.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())

    self.inputToolbar.contentView?.leftBarButtonItem = nil

    self.senderDisplayName = "User"

    self.senderId = ClientSenderId
}

// MARK: - JSQMessagesViewController delegate methods

override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)
    self.messages?.append(message!)

    if let textModeSwitchingCompletion = textModeSwitchingCompletion {
        textModeSwitchingCompletion.set(result: text as NSString)
        self.textModeSwitchingCompletion = nil
    }
    else {
        self.interactionKit?.text(inTextOut: text)
    }
    self.finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageData {

    return self.messages![indexPath.item]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didDeleteMessageAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Nothing happens here
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource {

    let message = self.messages![indexPath.item]
    if (message.senderId == self.senderId) {
        return self.outgoingBubbleImageData!
    }
    return self.incomingBubbleImageData!
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource? {

    let message = messages![indexPath.item]
    if message.senderId == ClientSenderId {
        return self.clientImage
    }
    return self.serverImage
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let messages = messages {
        return messages.count
    }
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = (super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell)
    let msg = self.messages?[indexPath.item]
    if !msg!.isMediaMessage {
        if (msg?.senderId == self.senderId) {
            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        else {
            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForCellTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 {
        let message = self.messages?[indexPath.item]
        return JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.shared().attributedTimestamp(for: message!.date)
    }
    return nil
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let message = self.messages?[indexPath.item]

    // iOS 7 sender name labels
    if (message?.senderId == self.senderId) {
        return nil
    }

    if indexPath.item - 1 > 0 {
        let previousMessage = self.messages?[indexPath.item - 1]
        if (previousMessage?.senderId == message?.senderId) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // Do not specify attributes to use the default values.
    return NSAttributedString(string: message!.senderDisplayName)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
    return nil
}

func composerTextView(_ textView: JSQMessagesComposerTextView, shouldPasteWithSender sender: Any) -> Bool {
    return true
}

}

 // MARK: - Bot Interaction Kit
 extension JeevesChatViewController: AWSLexInteractionDelegate {

func interactionKit(_ interactionKit: AWSLexInteractionKit, onError error: Error) {
    print("Error occurred: \(error)")
}

func interactionKit(_ interactionKit: AWSLexInteractionKit, switchModeInput: AWSLexSwitchModeInput, completionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSLexSwitchModeResponse>?) {
    self.sessionAttributes = switchModeInput.sessionAttributes
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let message: JSQMessage

        // Handle a successful transaction
        if (switchModeInput.dialogState == AWSLexDialogState.readyForFulfillment) {
            // Currently just displaying the slots return on ready for fulfillment
            if let slots = switchModeInput.slots {
                message = JSQMessage(senderId: ServerSenderId, senderDisplayName: "", date: Date(), text: "Slots:\n\(slots)")
                self.messages?.append(message)
                self.finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
            }
        } else {
                message = JSQMessage(senderId: ServerSenderId, senderDisplayName: "", date: Date(), text: switchModeInput.outputText!)
                self.messages?.append(message)
                self.finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
            }
    })
    // This can be expanded to take input from the user.
    let switchModeResponse  = AWSLexSwitchModeResponse()
    switchModeResponse.interactionMode = AWSLexInteractionMode.text
    switchModeResponse.sessionAttributes = switchModeInput.sessionAttributes
    completionSource?.set(result: switchModeResponse)

}

func interactionKitContinue(withText interactionKit: AWSLexInteractionKit, completionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSString>) {
    textModeSwitchingCompletion = completionSource
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set your credentialsProvider properly. 
AWSIdentityManager was never initialized to be called:

> ```
> let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: botRegion!, credentialsProvider: AWSIdentityManager.default().credentialsProvider)
> ```

if you are using AWS for S3 bucket you should use incognito and thus

```
let cognitoIdentityPoolId = //"XYZ"
let cognitoUnauthRoleArn = //"XYZ"
let cognitoAuthRoleArn =  //"XYZ"
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: #Wherever, identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId, unauthRoleArn: cognitoUnauthRoleArn, authRoleArn: cognitoAuthRoleArn, identityProviderManager: nil)
```

which you can then change your line to:

```
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: botRegion!, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
```

Comment: I downloaded the sample to make a comparison it uses the same line of code, how come it works there and not in my project?

Comment: check in the sample project's AppDelegate file, and let me know if its initialized there